# How to Chain Dynamic Series of Async Actions Using Redux Thunk?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, redux, redux-thunk

### The Norm

According to the official documentation (https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), I know that redux thunk allows dispatching a chain of async actions sequentially like so:

```
function makeSandwichesForEverybody() {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    return dispatch(
      makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('My Grandma')
    ).then(() =>
      Promise.all([
        dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('Me')),
        dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('My wife'))
      ])
    ).then(() =>
      dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('Our kids'))
    ).then(() =>
      dispatch(getState().myMoney > 42 ?
        withdrawMoney(42) :
        apologize('Me', 'The Sandwich Shop')
      )
    );
  }
}
```

### My Situation

However, what if I have a dynamic array of actions that I want to iterate through and call?

```
let arrOfActions = [];
arrOfActions.push(action1);
arrOfActions.push(action2);
arrOfActions.push(action3);
```

How can I chain these async actions iteratively using Promise logic? To best explain what I am thinking, I am hoping to do something like this:

```
function thunkActionCreator() {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    for (let key of arrOfActions) {
      dispatch(arrOfActions[key]()).then(
        // run next action in arrOfActions here
      )
    }
  }
}
```

**Is this dynamic iteration of function calls possible? If so, what is the syntax?**

For verification that you can indeed call functions in an array of functions, here is the resource I found: [How to store functions into an array and loop through each in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186880/how-to-store-functions-into-an-array-and-loop-through-each-in-javascript)

### Why A Dynamic Array of Actions?

There may be a better way to think of this, but the reason I am trying to use this implementation is because I have a series of functions that I need to call in a specific order. This array would be stored in Redux's store, and I am not sure how else to be able to call a series of functions in order from start to finish. Any other ideas would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upfront disclaimer;  I think the fact that you need to do this is evidence of deeper problems in your codebase.  You really shouldn't be queueing up a list of async functions that need to occur in a specific order and which you don't know of in advanced.  That's a number of red flags.

But can you do it?  Sure!

```
function enqueueDynamicArray(functionArray) {
    let p = Promise.resolve();
    for(index in functionArray) {
        p = p.then(functionArray[index]);
    }
    return p;
}
```

EDIT:  And per comments, if you can rely on the functions being synchronous;

```
function callDynamicArray(functionArray) {
    for(index in functionArray){
        functionArray[index]();
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice while still answering the question! Would you still say there are deeper problems if I am queueing up a list of sync functions that need to occur in a specific order? There is no need for the functions that I run in the queue to be async, just as long as I am running a dynamic number of functions in order.

Comment: I would still be skeptical of the situation that necessitates it, but the solution to it becomes a lot simpler.  I'll update the answer to include a non-promise version as well for the synchronous state.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick/helpful reply. How does your non-promise version work when using Redux dispatches, though? Since all of my functions are essentially Redux actions that update the state in different ways but MUST be synchronous, wouldn't a for loop of dispatch actions just fire them all asynchronously? Perhaps my understanding of Redux dispatching of actions is misguided. Any helpful thoughts on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Oh wow. According to the definition of dispatch in the [redux-docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatch), `The store's reducing function will be called with the current getState() result and the given action synchronously.` Feel free to correct, but this seems to mean that in order to fire dispatches synchronously out of a dynamic array, I would simply do a for loop of `dispatch(functionArray[index]());`